# Как сделать отправку через cURL только checked values из формы?

Tags: php, post, curl

Необходимо отсылать с помощью cURL не все значения формы типа checkbox, а только отмеченные. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

HTML-код

```
<form action="?" method="post">
<!-- обратите внимание поле name задается как массив при помощи скобок check[] -->
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2"/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить форму"/>
</form>
```

PHP-код

```
<?php

// если форма была отправлена
if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
  $keys=array();
// перебираем массив
  foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
/*  проверяем данные на соответсвие, в данном случае я проверяю на наличие цифровых символов в строке,
    именно они были переданы в форме в качестве значения value, если другое - используем, например, регулярное выражение */
    if(ctype_digit($value)) $keys[]=$value;
  }
// если был отмечен хотя бы один checkbox
  if(sizeof($keys)>0) {

// запускаем сеанс CURL
            $ch=curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/file.php?value='.base64_encode(implode("::",$keys)));
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,15);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'User-Agent that was used');
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'');
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        $info[]=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $info[]=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD);
         $errno=curl_errno($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
  }
}

?>
```

На другом сервере принимаем данные в переменной `$_GET['value']`, в файле `/file.php` и разделяем строку с помощью двойного двоеточия

```
  $result = explode('::',base64_decode($_GET['value']));
```

После, работаем с массивом `$result[]`

Возможно, для вашей задачи будет актуальной передача данных с помощью опции `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, она присутствует в коде в закомментированном виде.
Пример ее использования здесь: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @Тим у вас по тому вопросу уже имеется вполне подходящий ответ. Попробуйте сымитировать подключение через CURL к своему серверу, передав параметры и посмотрите в логах правильно ли передаются все значения через GET. Если все данные передаются на сервер в нужном порядке и форме, тогда потребуется решение проблемы с авторизацией. А проверка отмечен ли чекбокс идет через `if (isset ($_POST['checkbox_name']) && $_POST['checkbox_name'] == 'value')` , где `value` ожидаемое значение, а `checkbox_name` соответсвует наименованию для `<input type="checkbox" ... `

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь что не могу устроить в комментарии... Баллов не хватает.

Вообще браузер присылает только отмеченные checkbox. Но я не могу понять при чём тут cUrl , это эе php-шная функция.

Или вы имеете ввиду Ajax?
Можно например использую jQuery воспользоваться функцией [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: 1) Для добавления заказа нужно послать POST запрос, параметры запроса:

services - массив кодов выбранных услуг:
furniture - химчистка мягкой мебели
mattress - химчистка матрасов
carpet - химчистка ковров на дому
factory-carpet-cleaning - химчистка ковров на фабрике
cleaning - уборка помещений
other - иное

Пример передачи параметров:
services[0]=mattress&services[1]=cleaning&services[2]=factory-carpet-cleaning

Comment: Отправить из браузера? Или из php куда-то еще?

Comment: После обработки формы нужно послать POST запрос на http://.../api/

Comment: Если отправка формы производится из браузера, то там есть два варианта развития событий:

Comment: Извиняюсь, случайно отправил... Если отправка формы производится из браузера, то там есть два варианта развития событий: 1. если вы отправляете сразу форму, то отправятся только выбранные checkbox-ы, браузер сам не отошлет не выбранные. И второй, если из браузера посылается Ajax-ом. В этом случае вам надо выбрать только выбранные checkbox-ы и отправлять их. Выбрать можно как я написал выше используя jQuery либо стандарными средствами браузера. простейший селектор: document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked') и уже их и отсылать

Comment: Вот простой пример выбора: https://jsfiddle.net/58hv38cc/1/